# How to get total no of sold products in magento

Tags: magento

I want the total no of all the products sold in Magneto. So my question id How can i get total no of sold products in Magento?

Comment: are you want list total no sold qty  of a products?

Comment: I only want total no of sold products

Comment: are you looking report or you want to show in frontrnd

Comment: I want to show this in front end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use below code:-

```
$from ='2014-07-07';
$to =date('Y-m-d',time());
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')->addOrderedQty($from, $to, true)
->addAttributeToFilter('sku', 'Sample Product')->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc');
echo "<pre>";
print_R($_productCollection->getData());
exit;
```

Comment: This works for me
$from ='2014-07-07';
$to =date('Y-m-d',time());
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')->addOrderedQty($from, $to, true)
->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc');
echo "<pre>";
print_R($_productCollection->getData());
exit;